# Añadir un schema a una bd existente que ya tiene un schema y visualizarlo en el IDE robo3t

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Buenas estoy trabajando con **nodejs** , estuve programando mi backend en mongodb y para empezar cree el **schema usuario** , posteriormente me meti en el **IDE robo3t** y me conecte a la base de datos `personajes` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema viene a continuacion: he creado mi segunda tabla llama **personajes** y siguiendo los mismos procesos de creacion que con el **schema usuarios** no me crea,en este caso, esta nueva tabla.

A continuacion dejo el codigo:

**database.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const URI = 'mongodb://localhost/personajes';


mongoose.connect(URI)
.then( db => console.log('DB is connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));


module.exports = mongoose;
```

**usuario.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {Schema} = mongoose;


const usuarioSchema = new Schema({
    nombre_personal :{type: String, required : true},
    apel1_personal :{type: String, required : true},
    apel2_personal :{type: String, required : true},
    pais :{type: String, required : true},
    ciudad :{type: String, required : true},
    nombre_usuario :{type: String, required : true},
    password_usuario :{type: String, required : true},
    email_usuario :{type: String, required : true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('USUARIOS', usuarioSchema);
```

**personaje.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {Schema} = mongoose;


const personajeSchema = new Schema({
    nombre :{type: String, required : true},
    apellidos :{type: String, required : true},
    mundo :{type: String, required : true},
    lugar_mundo :{type: String, required : true},
    raza :{type: String, required : true},
    edad :{type: String, required : true},
    clase :{type: String, required : true},
    oficio :{type: String, required : true},
    historia :{type: String, required : true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('PERSONAJES', personajeSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Hola @josanangel,

Me parece que tu problema esta en la URL que le pasas a la conexión de MongoDB que no le estas indicando el puerto: 
`const URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/personajes';`

Por defecto, MongoDB elige el 27017 sino lo has cambiado en tu configuración.

Ademas, según las imágenes y código que muestras, la colección que escribes en 'NodeJS' no concuerda con la que tienes en 'ROBO3T', debería de ir en minúsculas (`usuario`).

Espero que te haya podido ayudar en tu problema.

Un saludo